# Random assignment of treatment and control using else condition

Tags: stata

I am trying to learn else condition loops in Stata. To do this I'm trying random assignment into treatment and control. However, I keep getting the error: '{' invalid

I can do it normally:

```
g treat = 0 if random > 0.5 
replace treat = 1 if random < 0.5
```

However, I want to try it out with the else condition. Moreover, additional resources to learn the if condition would also be greatly appreciated. The else condition loop that I am trying:

```
clear all
// Set the seed for the random number generator
set seed 98034

set obs 10000
// Generate 1000 random numbers between 0 and 1
g random = runiform()

// For each observation, assign it to the treatment group if the random number is less than 0.5, and to the control group otherwise

forvalues i = 1(1)10000 {
    g treatment = 1 if random[`i'] < 0.5 {
        else {
            treatment[`i'] = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `gen treatment = runiform() < 0.5` generates two identically sized groups on average, it is not guaranteed that the groups are the same size. Therefore, I think random assignment should be done by random ranking.

```
clear all
// Set the seed for the random number generator
set seed 98034
set obs 10000
// Assign treatment using 1000 random numbers between 0 and 1
gen  rand = runiform() 
sort rand
gen treatment = (_n <= _N/2)
tab treatment
```

Technically, to make the randomization truly reproducible you also need to set the Stata version (for example, `version 16`) and stably sort the data (for example `isid idvar, sort`) before using `runiform()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way to get what you want:

```
clear all
// Set the seed for the random number generator
set seed 98034
set obs 10000
// Assign treatment using 10000 random numbers between 0 and 1
gen treatment = runiform() < 0.5
```

As you've found out, it is legal, but more long-winded, to do it this way

```
gen random = runiform() 
gen treatment = 1 if random < 0.5 
replace treatment = 0 if random >= 0.5
```

where I've corrected for the finite if very small probability that the random number is exactly 0.5.

Using a loop is completely uncalled for, and very inefficient, but this would be legal code:

```
generate treatment = . 

forvalues i = 1(1)10000 {
    if random[`i'] < 0.5 replace treatment = 0 in `i' 
    else replace treatment = 1 in `i' 
}
```

Even then it would be more efficient to `generate` the variable as 0 and just `replace` it when the value needs to be 1.

There are several errors in your code:

E1. You can't `generate` a variable more than once. Second time around the loop, the `generate` refers to a variable that already exists.

E2. You're confusing the `if` command with the `if` qualifier. This is often done. There wouldn't need to be two devices if they were the same really. See
https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1536867X231175349 for a recent review.

E3. A direct assignment like

```
treatment[`i'] = 0
```

is illegal in Stata, although something similar is allowed in Mata.

E4. It is also illegal to put subscripts on the left-hand side of an assignment.